# Stacking / layering background shapes on TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-xml, android-shape

I have a simple game where a user can highlight words:

[image]

Each letter is a `TextView`. To highlight, the background is set to a shape like:

top_curve.xml
[image]

The code looks like this:

```
// Method returns a Drawable like:
// return ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.top_curve);
letterGrid[row][column].textView.background = getHighlightBackgroundForTile(dragDirection, highLightPosition);
```

My problem now is when I want to draw over a previously highlighted `TextView` but I'm overwriting the previous background like so:

[image]

Is there a way I can stack these backgrounds on top of each other rather than replacing them?

Comment: Yes, you can make a LayerDrawable to combine multiple drawables and set that. But instead of doing that, why not just make 4 additional drawables with a single corner rounded?

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know about that. If I draw a single rounded one, the colours all have to be the same so I think LayerDrawable is the way to go